# I want to zip my test results folder,but i want this to take place after the onComplete Function in protractor-conf file

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I want to zip my test results folder and have a method to do the same,but i 
want this method to be executed after the onComplete Function as i am 
generating the HTML report in the onComplete Function and if i have both 
the methods in the onComplete Function, the zipped folder is being created 
but with 0 KB,i guess this is because it has zipped the folder before the 
report gets generated.How can i execute a method after the onComplete 
 function.

```
    onComplete: function () {
    // Log any browser console errors that have not been logged in specs

    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browserVersion = caps.get('version');
        platform = caps.get('platform');
        var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');

        testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'E2E Test Summary Report',
            outputPath: './build/test/results/E2E_Test_Summary_Report',
            outputFilename: 'e2e_TestResult_'+datetime,
            screenshotPath: './build/test/results/E2E_Test_Summary_Report/screenshots',
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: true,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
            browserPrefix: true
        };
        new HTMLReport().from('./build/test/results/e2e-results.xml', testConfig);
    });
    zipE2EReport();

},
var zipE2EReport = function zipE2EReport() {

var output = fs1.createWriteStream('build/test/results/E2E_Test_Summary_Report.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip');


output.on('close', function () {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

archive.pipe(output);

//archive.bulk([
//    { expand: true, cwd: 'src', src:'build/test/results/E2E_Test_Summary_Report'}
//]);

archive.directory('build/test/results/E2E_Test_Summary_Report', 'E2E_Test_Summary_Report');

archive.finalize();

};

 Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is move the zip function into the `then` chain of generate HTML report, please see below code example:

```
capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
   .....
   return new HTMLReport().from('./build/test/results/e2e-results.xml', testConfig);

}).then(function(){
   // move the zip function into the next `then`.
   return zipE2EReport();
});
```

Comment: I tried doing that,but i get the same results,It does not throw any error and i get a compressed zip folder with 0KB.

Comment: try add `return` before `new HTMLReport()`  and add `return` before `zipE2EReport()`

Comment: Appreciate your help but the above hasn't been able to resolve it.

Comment: Have updated the zip function in the question.Is there something wrong i am doing there.

Comment: Can you get the correct zip file if run the `zipE2EReport()` separately? you can copy the function into a new js file and put any files in folder before execute the function.

Comment: the `zipE2EReport()` works fine if i have it alone in the onComplete label.

Comment: If you put some files in `build/test/results/E2E_Test_Summary_Report` and `E2E_Test_Summary_Report` folder, then run test script (not run zipE2EReport alone ), you still get empty zip?

Comment: Yes,even if i have existing files in the `E2E_Test_Summary_Report`,and then run the test,it still shows a zip folder with 0KB.

Comment: ok, tell me which package for `HTMLReport` and `archive`, i can try them on my local.

Comment: Its `protractor-html-reporter-2:1.0.4` and archiver: 1.1.0.Thanks

Comment: I tried on my local with your specified version, it worked fine. you can find my workable nodejs project from https://github.com/yongcy/stackoverflow/tree/master/zip-jasmine-html-report,  Can you find the html report file under `E2E_Test_Summary_Report ` after running your script? If not, so the zip file will includes an empty folder.  Before run my script, please execute `npm install` and `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update` at first.

Comment: Thank you so much for that.I tried it,and i can see the html report under the `E2E_Test_Summary_Report` but the zip folder is still empty.Did the zip folder generate properly for you.

Comment: Yes, it includes a folder with a html file inside it, you can run my project to verify that.  you can put my `spec.js` in your project and modify your protractor file to only run my `spec.js`, then to see the zip will include the html or not.  When you try to find a cause of a problem,  Keeping project as simple as possible at beginning, then  add more into project, repeat again and again util it don't work. then you get the cause.

Comment: Thanks.Ill try it and let you know.

Comment: If my project work fail on your local, please try to upgrade Nodejs,  I used v8.9.4. And if my project worked again after nodejs upgraded. your  problem is caused by not compatible  nodejs version.